# Programming language API sidebar in gedit

Tags: programming, gedit

Is there a plugin for gedit to enable me to have the API for a particular language open in a sidebar?

I'm currently working in Java, and it would be useful to have a tree type document with the details of the API keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if that can be achieved in gedit, but there are several alternatives for this case, such as [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html) which imho is the most lightweight and will give you the reference information in autocompletion popup as shown in the **Edit Preferences**.

Give it a try, it isn't that different from or more resource-demanding than gedit.

A php file highlighted and html reference information in a popup.

[image]

An html file highlighted and html reference information in a popup.

[image]

Edit/Preferences Language support config.

[image]

Supported languages, which include but are not limited to Javascript

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may consider contributing to the community by writing a Plugin for the job that you want to achieve. [Here](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo) is a good starting point from Gnome team.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't plugins for gedit, but you might like them:  The program [devhelp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/devhelp) [image: Install devhelp]
 <strike>and the website http://www.gotapi.com/html</strike>

Comment: The gotapi website seems to be no more.